# How to display which number was taken as random from image?

Tags: uilabel

Can someone please explain, what I should add to code to display in UILabel which number was taken as random from image?
Here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var diceImageView1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var diceImageView2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
@IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {        
    let diceArray = [ #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceOne"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceTwo"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceThree"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFour"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFive"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceSix") ]
    diceImageView1.image = diceArray.randomElement()
    diceImageView2.image = diceArray.randomElement()
    Label.text = (diceImageView1.image)
}
```

Here's error I'm getting:

Cannot assign value of type 'UIImage?' to type 'String?'

Thank you!